# Deploy ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework web application with database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis

I have a working ASP.NET MVC web app I developed with Entity Framework with a database-first approach. The database was already existing. When I run it in Visual Studio, everything works fine.

I then published the site and setup an IIS web site on my computer for it. Pages that do not require data work fine. But the site cannot access the database. I have tried creating a mixed mode SQL Server id, changing the odbc connection to login as the admin user, and adding the IUSR user to SQL Server. No luck.

How can I get the local site to access the database from IIS just like it does through IIS Express?

Here is the error page:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Cannot open database "PVS" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\PVS'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "PVS" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\PVS'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "PVS" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\PVS'.]

Comment: Because the app pool on your local IIS is running as You and you are using integrated Authentication for SQL Server.  On the server, the app pool is running as some service account that doesn't have a login setup in SQL Server.  You can either give this service account access to your SQL Server instance and DB or create a SQL Server login with access and change your connection to use that.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: @Fran, "Because the app pool on your local IIS is running as You and you are using integrated Authentication for SQL Server" is incorrect. IIS Express is not "local IIS", and IIS Express also has no app pool.

Comment: I realized I left out express after my original comment.  I was waiting for the OP to comment back.

Comment: That's ok.  Your initial response pointed me back to the app pool and I found the setting I missed originally.  It is working now.  This is a database first app with MVC and Entity Frameworks.  What is the best method to deploy it with the app and database in one package?